# Действие, при пустой таблице Python

Tags: python, if

Всем привет! Есть цикл, который строит и обрабатывает таблицы свеч бинанса по каждой паре. По окончанию каждого цикла выдает название монеты и ее цену с данными из таблицы:

```
print(use_coin)    
print(use_klines['Open_time'].tolist())
print(use_klines['Open_time'].tolist())
```

Но в обработке отсеивается большее количество монет, таблица use_klines остается пустой, и на выходе я получаю что то вроде:

```
OMGUSDT
[]
[]
THETAUSDT
[]
[]
ENJUSDT
[1668194460000]
[0.3438]
MITHUSDT
[]
[]
```

Как внутри цикла задать условие, чтобы при пустой таблице команды ptint не выполнялись?

PS ну и подскажите, пожалуйста, как преобразовать значения столбца Open_time в привычный вид)) Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Что-то у вас второй и третий принт одинаковы. И добавьте несколько строк первоначальной таблицы.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте сравнивать длину списка с нулем, т.е. :

```
if len(use_klines) > 0:
   #ваш print
else:
    pass
```

Comment: Спасибо! Работает!